# How To Trigger rerender of react component once get request data is passed to usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I've observed that there are already many questions parallel to this one but I have yet to find a solution to my case.

I'm attempting to dynamically display data within this component retrieved from my api. The page renders upon first load successfully however once the data received from the get request is passed to the state, a re-render doesn't occur.

Ive tried referencing the data in different ways within `setProduct` and I've included a conditional render that checks the length of the array to determine whether to display "loading..." or the actual data once it's in state. The `console.log(product)` after the useEffect confirms that the get response does come back successfully with the data I want to use.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Footer from '../../components/Footer';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';
import Newsletter from '../../components/Newsletter';
import {
    Container,
    ImgContainer,
    Wrapper,
    Image,
    InfoContainer,
    Title,
    Desc,
    Price,  
    FilterContainer,
    Filter,
    FilterSize,
    FilterTitle,
    FilterSizeOption,
    AmountContainer,
    AddContainer,
    Amount,
    AddToCartBtn,
    } from './ProductPage.styles';
import { productCategories } from '../../data';
import { Add, Remove } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import {publicRequest} from "../../requestMethods"
import axios from "axios"

const ProductPage = () => {

  const location = useLocation();
  const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];

  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    const getProduct = async () => {

      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:2000/api/products/find/" + id);

      setProduct({...product, res})

      return product;
    };

    getProduct();

  }, [id])

  console.log(product)
  
  return (
    <Container>
        <Navbar />
        <Wrapper>

          {product.length > 0 ? 
            <>
              <ImgContainer>
              <Image src={product.img} />
              </ImgContainer>
              <InfoContainer>
                <Title>
                  { product.title }
                </Title>
                <Desc>{ product.desc }</Desc>
                <Price>$ { product.price }</Price>
                <FilterContainer>
                  <Filter>
                    <FilterTitle>
                      size
                    </FilterTitle>
                        <FilterSize> 
                          {product.size.map( (s) => (
                            <FilterSizeOption key={s}>{s}</FilterSizeOption>
                          ))}
                        </FilterSize>  
                  </Filter>
                </FilterContainer>

                <AddContainer>
                  <AmountContainer>
                    <Remove style={{cursor: "pointer"}}/>
                    <Amount>1</Amount>
                    <Add style={{cursor: "pointer"}}/>

                  </AmountContainer>
                  <AddToCartBtn>add to cart</AddToCartBtn>
                </AddContainer>
              </InfoContainer>
          </>
          : <>
              <p>Loading...</p>
            </>
          }
          </Wrapper>
        
        <Newsletter />
        <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ProductPage;
```

Please advise on changes I need to make to trigger a rerender of the component so that the data stored in the product state can be displayed in the jsx.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're setting your `product` state to an object after your fetch when it should be an array.

Comment: Hi @pilchard, thank you for the reply. So when I change the setting of the product state to an array, the component renders for a second then goes blank. I also receive the following error in the console, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: product.size is undefined.

Comment: @ pilchard what I've done now is change the initial value of the product state to an empty object and also the setting of the product state to an object with the get data. However, my original issue of no re-render still remains even though the previously mentioned console error doesnt occur.

Comment: An object doesn't have a `length` property, so your condition will never be met. Either find a condition in your `product` object that is meaningful, or use an array but map it. `{product.title !== undefined ? ...`

Comment: Thank you again man @pilchard, went with an array for the state and state setting, mapping through the array got it rendering like I needed.